# Am I using file_get_contents properly?

Tags: php, html

Lately, I was messing around with HTML and PHP (which I just started to learn).
I found out, that I can use `file_get_contents` to fetch the contents of a text file.
So I copied the contents of my HTML file in a plain PHP file and just replaced the text, which was written in the HTML with

```
  <?PHP 
    $name = file_get_contents('this.txt');
    echo $name;
  ?>
```

I wondered If I could still use the links I which where embedded in the text. I could.

```
<a href="https://optifine.net/downloads" target="_blank">Optifine</a>
```

This is in the .txt file and works. 
But now I don't know if this is the "right" way of doing it. 
Obviously it works, but does it always work or is there a better way?

edit/extension:

file_get_contens:   
expection: gets the pure contents form a file without prosessing e.g. links etc.
reality: fetches the text from the txt file and handles it as a html file thus prossessingthe links thus showing them properly

include:
expection: gets filecontents and prosesses file according to its extension.
reality: gets contents from textfile and prosesses it as an html file thus showing the links properly.

WHY

Comment: PHP doesn't care about whatever markup in your plain text files. It will always work. If your files are full-on HTML files, a `.html` extension might be more appropriate, but it doesn't make a functional difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents) is to fetch data form a file into a variable.

What you want to do is "include" the content from a file into your current file. For that, you should use either [`include`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents) (it won't crash if the file doesn't exist but a warning) or [`require`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents) (it will crash if the file doesn't exist).

```php
<?php
include 'this.html';
```

As you mention that you are new in PHP, I suggest you learn:

- How [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) works.
- How to do a proper separation between the logic and the view in order to decouple the view from the logic behind that produces the data that need to be rendered.

Learning Symfony (or Laravel) framework will help you to understand these concepts very easily :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will look into the stuff you mentioned. But now, my brain has figured out a new thing to be confused about. 
Shouldn't the links only work when I use include then? Because I thought that file get contents only fetches the CONTENTS without any formatting or processing. Its (for me) logical, that include can process the links from the file. But why does the file get contents exactly the same thing then when it just fetches the pure contents?

Comment: if you want to fetch the content from a link/URL you should use curl(native PHP): https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php or even better use Guzzle (third party library): https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `file_get_contents` to fetch text.

Better way for fetching external text/code would be to use `include` as you can also use *.html*, *.php*...

```
<?php
  include 'externalfile.html';
?>
```

You can also use `require`, which is almost same thing except:

> The `include` and `require` statements are identical, except upon failure:
>
> - `require` will produce a fatal error (E_COMPILE_ERROR) and stop the script
> - `include` will only produce a warning (E_WARNING) and the script will continue

[W3schools reference for `include`](https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_includes.asp)